# Reason for parentheses after read, truncate and close commands?

Tags: python

Could someone explain to me what the parentheses after the 
`.read()`, `.truncate()`and `.close()` commands are doing?

I'm confused by why they're empty and why it isn't written as:
`read(filename)`, `truncate(filename)`, and `close(filename)` rather than 
`filename.read()`, `filename.truncate()`, and `filename.close()`?

But `open` is written as `open(filename)` and not `filename.open()`

Comment: Have you studied `class`es yet? This is a question of functions vs methods.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You are right, in this case the duplicate is not appropriate either. Reopening it.

Comment: @Selcuk it's more like "unclear what you're asking" than "duplicate"!

Comment: To be fair I think it is pretty clear. The lack of formatting makes it a bit hard to read.

Comment: Well, I don't think we, or even the person who asked, understood what the question is. It seems to be a general confusion about where the data is stored and what functions, classes and instances are.

Comment: It's not `read(filename)`, it's `file.read(number_of_bytes)`. `read()`is a method of the `file`class and the `()` following its name cause it to be called with the argument value inside them (which happens to be optional for this particular method and can be left out).

Answer (score 3):

Those parentheses `()` are for actually calling a certain function instead of merely referring to it.

Consider for example:

```
def func():
    return "I am being called!"


print(func)
# <function func at 0x7f41f59a6b70>

print(func())
# I am being called!
```

---

Regarding the: `func(x)` versus `x.func()` syntax, this is a design / stylistic choice.

The first syntax is associated to procedural design / style, while the second syntax is associated to explicitly object-oriented design / style.

Python (as well as many other general purpose languages) support both.

When `func` was designed as:

```
def func(x):
    ...
```

you would use the procedural style.

When `func` is designed as:

```
class MyX(object):
    def func(self):
        ...
```

you would use the object-oriented style.
Note that this would require `x` to be of type `MyX` (or a sub-class of it).

More info is available in Python tutorials, e.g. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Final note: in some programming languages (notably `D` and `nim`) there is the concept of [Uniform Function Call Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax), which basically allows you to write function and then have it called with whichever syntax (procedural or object-oriented) you prefer.

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense :) Super appreciate your response!